# Bivariate Transformation of Two Independent Normal

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, transformation

Suppose X, Y are independent normal $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Suppose we perform bivariate transformation such that

$U=X^2+Y^2$, $V=X/\sqrt{U}$.

My question is how to get the support of $U,V$.

$U$ : it is obvious that it is between 0 and infinity.

V : I am not sure how it is between -1 and 1.

Can someone explain in detail?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualize $X$ and $Y$ as corresponding to a random ordered pair $(X,Y) \in \mathbb R^2$ in the Cartesian coordinate plane.  Then $\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ is the distance of $(X,Y)$ to the origin $(0,0)$.  Then $X/\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ is the ratio of the $X$-coordinate to this distance; i.e., it is the **cosine** of the angle that the vector $(X,Y)$ forms with the positive $X$-axis.

Comment: I have a similar situation but a tough time visualizing the following: originally 0<x,y<1. Defined U=XY, V=X. 0<u<v<1 is the correct answer, but I cannot visualize why U is capped by V.

Comment: @FrankSwanton Simple.  If $0 < X, Y < 1$, then $X = 1 \cdot X \ge Y \cdot X$, which implies $V \ge U$.

Comment: did you mean, then $Y=1$.

Comment: No.  If $0 < Y < 1$, then multiply this inequality by $X$ to get $$0 < XY < X,$$ and since $X > 0$, none of the inequalities reverse direction.  Then you immediately conclude $XY < X$.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.

Comment: hero, can I ask you a related question?